# Increase font size on new iOS 8 SE app?

Tags: feature-request, support, ios-app, ipad

Hello SE iOS app dev team and other interested parties,

Is it possible to increase the font sizes (relative to each other as a global scalar) on the iPad app? I can't see any app preferences/settings to do this...

If there isn’t a way to do so yet, could that functionality be added?

I recommend looking at The Guardian app for a good example of having a discreet (and discrete! ha ha!) ever-present font size controller on each page, that also uses a left-edge sidebar as part of its UI:

[image: Screenshot and description of font resize feature example from The Guardian newspaper app]

Not only is it a good option for legibility, it's also very good for avoiding temporary blindness from having to hold one's device too close!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

We do not have functionality to change the font sizes for the Stack Exchange app *only*.

However, the app supports Dynamic Type, which is a device-wide setting. You can change it by going to the Settings App -> Display & Brightness -> Text Size.
There you will see a slide control to change the text size. Changing it there will affect most font sizes in the app.

(Note these are iOS 8 instructions; steps for iOS 7 might be slightly different, but the functionality is there).

Comment: Or easier, under "Display & Brightness -> Text Size"

Comment: @BenjaminR updated answer to clarify things a bit.

Comment: @ArieLitovsky Thanks!