# The text size in the Stack Exchange app should be user-configurable

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, android-app

Why can we not adjust the size of the text in the Stack Exchange app? The tiny size text may be unhealthy to my eyes. Can the ability to adjust the text size be added?

Comment: I'm not sure if the text size is influenced by accessibility features of the mobile OS or not, but you should likely specify which platform (Android/iOS) you're using the app on.

Comment: It's Android. But I have installed it on iOS, too. Both of them cannot adjust the text size free.

Comment: (on iOS, the app supports Dynamic Type: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/243111/increase-font-size-on-new-ios-8-se-app)

Comment: Thanks. How about Androids? I suppose this feature is very important for everyone who love this app and health reading.

Comment: As far as I can see not possible in android app and not requested yet, so removing the iOS tag. /cc @Tim.

Comment: On the iPad, Im already using large font sizes.  The Stack app doesnt follow those sizes set in iOS settings. They are still substantially smaller than in other DynamicType apps.  This really needs to be updated to better respect system preferences, or, at a minimum, allow us to increase it in the app itself. Its a simple change but has a *huge* impact.

Answer (score 6):

As of the next update, 1.0.61, both the default text size is larger (to actually match the design guide's standards) and we now respect the accessibility options everywhere.

This means if the UI is still too small, you can go to your phone's settings --> Display --> Font Size and change it.

Comment: On the iPad, Im already using large font sizes.  The Stack app doesnt follow those sizesset in iOS settings. They are still substantially smaller than in other apps.  This really needs to be updated.

Answer (score 0):

The text size in the android app is dependent on the text size of your phone. You can adjust it in the general settings.

On my Sony Xperia with Android 4.3 that's in Settings > Display > Font size.

Comment: This [won't change most text](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/221260/increasing-system-text-size-only-makes-comment-text-bigger) right now, but we're working on it.